# Python - How to use the value of a python variable as a python list

Tags: python, list

I have:

```
Variable1 = "list1"
```

and

```
list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

How to access/manipulate list1 items (and apply all the standard list operator/functions to list1) via the variable Variable1

Something like

```
token = random.choice($UnknownOperator$(Variable1))
and token would be equal either to a b c or d
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you stored `list1` in a *dictionary* instead, you'd not have this problem. [Keep your data out of your variable names](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've finally stopped misspelling your name! I think I spend too much time on SO........

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use `globals()`:

```
x = "list1"

list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

>>> print globals()[x]
["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

You can also do it as:

```
x = "list1"

list1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

get_var = lambda a: globals()[a]

>>> print get_var(x)
["a", "b", "c", "d"]

>>> print random.choice(get_var(x))
c
```

But as @MartijnPieters said, dictionaries is a *much* better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to this question is, you don't. Use a dict.

```
lists = {'list1': ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
         'list2': ["foo", "bar", "baz"]}

token = random.choice(lists[Variable1])
```

All direct answers to this question are ugly hacks that make it hard for tools like editors, debuggers and code checkers to analyze your program.

Answer (score 1):

For the RIGHT way to do this:

```
import random

dict_of_lists = {"list1":['a','b','c','d']}
variable_1 = "list1"

token = random.choice(dict_of_lists[variable_1])
```

Using the `globals()` dictionary, as many have pointed out, is a Bad Idea for the reason that Martijn Pieters gave in his comment to your question. Use a dictionary instead and key by the "variable name" you need to access.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [7]: a = "foo"

In [8]: b = "a"

In [9]: globals()[b]
Out[9]: 'foo'
```

But you shouldn't have to do this.